# What capacitor do I need for an AMS1117-3.3 regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, esp32

I want to use an AMS1117-3.3 regulator to power an ESP32D chip that will consume 1A. The regulator will be powered by a 5V 1A supply. 5V at the regulator input to 3.3v at the output. How many capacitors should I use with the AMS1117? The [technical sheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet you linked specifies a single 22uF tantalum cap on the output (see Application Hints - Stability). Bulk capacitance on the input is up to you if you want it.